# How to order files in NiFi based on a timestamp in the filename?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm listing files from a directory, then parsing a timestamp out of their filename. I then need to process the files in order. I tried to use the EnforceOrder processor, but it's not designed to enforce order when there are large numerical gaps between the elements, like there would be in timestamps. The Priority Attribute Prioritizer has other issues...

1. It processes *higher* priorities first, so it would process them
       in reverse.
2. I dont see that it has any ability to queue for a certain period of time. So unless files were all dropped at the same time, it couldn't guarantee the order.

Is there a recommended approach for what I'm attempting to do?

Filenames would have a timestamp with some specified format (below is MM-dd-yyyy)

- MyFile_11-30-2018.txt
- MyFile_3-28-2018.txt

They need to be processed in order chronologically based on that timestamp. So for those two files, the second one would need to be processed before the first.

Comment: please provide an example for the filenames with timestamp and the desired order for them

Comment: added an example of the file names

Comment: if you can change date format to `yyyy-MM-dd` then sorting files by name will work. otherwise you can parse the date from filename, reformat it to `yyyy-MM-dd`, store it into `priority` attribute, and use `PriorityAttributePrioritizer` on queue

Comment: Unfortunately I can't control the date format. That solution is suitable for some cases, but it feels like a hack, and it doesn't work for every format scenario.

Comment: why? all the dates/timestamps could be converted to single date-format `yyyy-MM-dd` that is sortable...

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd is not a full timestamp. Timestamp strings are not guaranteed to be sortable. For instance, if they contained the timezone information, then that won't work.

Comment: ok. convert all to UTC timezone and use format with miliseconds: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` - absolutely sortable

Comment: I can try that to confirm it works, but is that really the best approach that is possible in NiFi? In addition, what happens when you want to add a delay to handle catching files when they don't arrive at once? The EnforceOrder processor has this feature, but the queue doesn't.