# NiFI:Passing a flowfile to the next processor by datetime from filename

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow where the flowfile will go through the flow toward the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor to execute a python script to do some process. The file that run in the flow have a name format as a date (MMdd_HHmm) for example:`0505_1015.csv` `0505_1030.csv` `0505_1045.csv` and so on. But in my flow I need each file to run in order(if those are in the flow at the same time) so it is not first in first out but file that are in the flow which name that has less date and time need to run and go into the processor first.

So, from the example, if `0505_1015.csv` `0505_1030.csv` `0505_1045.csv`are currently in the flow waiting to run in the next processor. `0505_1015.csv` will get into the processor first then after it finish running, `0505_1030.csv` will be execute in the processor.

So, if the files are in the flow it should run from the first date time. [image: order]As shwon in the picture, if there are more than one flowfile in the flow, the one that will execute first is the one that has less datetime in it name.

I have read something about `EnforceOrder` and `prioritizer` and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898804/how-to-order-files-in-nifi-based-on-a-timestamp-in-the-filename?rq=1) but still I cannot figure how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: it seems you have fixed incremental value added to the file name, why don`t you use a loop for this task ?

Comment: the  incremental value added to the filename is just a format that I will get from a file name which the source is GCS. The new file will be added to the GCS periodically which I used `ListGCSBucket` processor to get the new file to the flow. So, normally it won't cause any problem but I just want to make sure if the files come in at the same time, the file with less date on it filename will be process first @Up_One

Comment: Ok, i assume this files have creation timestamp, this can be used to enforce the order of processing.

Comment: So, how can I enforce order from it filename?

Comment: Hi, look for PriorityAttributePrioritizer in NiFi Docs https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.htm, learn how to use the priority attribute. This will do the trick

Comment: link seem to be broken but will search on the keyword

Comment: hi, i missed the "l" at the end :) , sorry is .html not .htm